# Getting NullPointerException in Unit test for MockMvc performed

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, mockmvc

I'm running a Unit test In my application's Controller and I'm getting a NullPointerException. Here are the details.

The Controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserMigrationController {

    UserService userService;

    @Value("${SOURCE_DNS}")
    private String sourceDns;

    @Autowired
    public UserMigrationController(UserRepository userRepository, DocumentRepository documentRepository) {
        userService = new UserService(userRepository, documentRepository);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getUsers", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserData>> getUsersForList() throws Exception {

        List<UsersData> usersDataList = UserService.getUsersForList();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(usersDataList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

The UserData is just a simple

```
public record UserData(String id, String name) {
}
```

And here is my test class:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UserMigrationControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private UserService userService;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}

@Test
void should_get_users_for_list() throws Exception {
    String id = "id";
    String name = "name";
    UserData userData = new UserData(id, name);
    List<UserData> response = new ArrayList<>();
    response.add(userData);
    when(userService.getUsersForList())
            .thenReturn(response);

    mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/users/getUsers")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept("application/json"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

As I can see, all annotations are in the right place. But when I run a test, I get NullPointerException like this:

```
Cannot invoke "com.package.usersapi.service.UserService.getUsersForList()" because "this.userService" is null
```

Comment: Do you mocked UserService? Do you annotated your test class with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) or others runner?

Comment: Please show us: 1. Annotations on the test class. 2. Annotations or initialization of userService and mockMvc in test class.

Comment: Can I know the reason why are you creating an object of UserService in UserMigrationController using new operator? Looks like this is causing issue.

Comment: @mamo >> I've edited my post, adding the annotations you asked for.

Comment: @Lesiak I'm sorry for the omission.  I've updated my post with relevant info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I needed to mock repositories from the constructor in the Controller class. The test class should look like this:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UserMigrationControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private UserService userService;

@MockBean
private UserRepository userRepository;

@MockBean
private DocumentRepository documentRepository;

// the rest of the code
```

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I would make following amendments:

1. In prod code: inject UserService to your controller, instead of creating one in the constructor:

```java
@Autowired
public UserMigrationController(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

Currently you are not interacting with the mock you created in your test. UserService must be a spring bean - annotating it with `@Service` should do the job.

2. You are using wrong annotations in your test.
   For this kind of test @WebMvcTest is ideal:

```java
@WebMvcTest(UserMigrationController.class)
class UserMigrationControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private UserService userService;

@Test
void should_get_users_for_list() throws Exception {
}
```

See: [Unit Testing With @WebMvcTest](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#unit-testing-with-webmvctest)

Note: You no longer need to call `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks`